# Store innerhtml by jQuery in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, innerhtml

I have

```
<div id="ulAndil" runat="server">

</div>
```

and button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAssignJudToCourse" runat="server" Text="تاكيد " 
      CssClass="button" CausesValidation="false" 
      OnClientClick="javascript:getShape();" 
      OnClick="btnAssignJudToCourse_Click" Visible="false" />
```

At runtime I create a lot of sortable html controls and then click confirm
I want to save inner html of this div before postback of button in session or anything

Using jQuery so when user click the button jQuery take inner html of div and stores it in cookie session any thing to store it after postback I can retrieve it

Please I want the exact code for this jQuery or javascript method and how to call on button

Comment: Are you using HTML5? You could store it in session or localstorage then.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the generated HTML in a hidden field and postback.

Say getShape() is your javascript function

```
function getShape()
{

//your validations applied

document.getElementById('hdnHTML').value = document.getElementById('ulAndil').value;

return true;

}
```

where hdnHTML is the hidden element of HTML.

Comment: ok after post back i can to retriev the inner html from hidden file?

Comment: i wrote code every time enter to function topld me that ulAndil div is null
but i saw code generated in html in ulAndil div

Comment: are you getting value using  ulAndil.innerHtml